# How do spotify and other big banner apps display customized content on the wall post

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, foursquare

I just saw this in my news feed

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/836/spotifywallpost.png/

How does spotify add these custom play buttons and the list of songs? Can I do it for my app as well? Or does Facebook provide these special features for certain big banner apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook provides this functionality for certain apps. You can build some pretty sweet stuff with Open Graph [Actions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/opengraph/actions/), [Objects](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/opengraph/objects/) and [Aggregations](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/opengraph/aggregations/) though.

Answer (score 1):

> How does spotify add these custom play buttons and the list of songs?

By embedding a Flash player into their posts. The relevant keyword is [Feed Gaming](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/feed-gaming/).

Comment: is the space for the animated content limited? or can i specify it. I want the enitre post to be one animation, nothing else